# Modification to Google Maps Api code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api

```
var options = {
map_frame_id: "mapframe",
    map_window_id: "mapwindow",
    lat_id: "filter_lat",
    lng_id: "filter_lng",
    addr_id: "filter_address",
    lat: "37.7749295",
    lng: "-122.4194155",
    map_zoom: 13 
}

$('#mapaddress').autogeocomplete(options);
```

Right now lat and lng code are displayed in 2 different inputs with:

```
lat_id: "filter_lat",
lng_id: "filter_lng",
```

Is is possible to add a third one that contains both of the above?

I have tried getting the code with jquery straight from the inputs but autogeocomplete scripts is stopping it for some reason so I thought I would try and just update the main script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add something to the autogeocomplete script like this (this would change your `input` on select) :

```
$("#yourid").val(ui.item.latitude + "," + ui.item.longitude);
```

to this section of the code (line 106->109)

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#" + lat_id).val(ui.item.latitude);
    $("#" + lng_id).val(ui.item.longitude);
},
```

you could add an option for the `id` of the `input` you want to update quite simply too

[Source for Autogeocomplete here](https://github.com/lorenzsell/Geocoded-Autocomplete/blob/master/static/js/jquery.autogeocomplete.js)

Or

if you do not want to modify the plugin, try :

```
$('#filter_lat, #filter_lng').change(function() {
    $('#yourid').val($('#filter_lat').val() + "," + $('#filter_lng').val());
});
```

Comment: I've added it and it looks like this but it's not doing anything to that input...could there be a mistype? Here is the code:

select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#" + lat_id).val(ui.item.latitude);
                    $("#" + lng_id).val(ui.item.longitude);
     $("#google_maps_code").val(ui.item.latitude + "," + ui.item.longitude);

                },

Comment: @Satch3000 worked ok for me locally - works on a select list - try moving the code down to line 139 in the `setMap` function and doing `$("#google_maps_code").val(lat+ "," + lng);` as thats called on the callback from getting the coords from google